# Index Match Multiple Criteria Row and Column without using Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm getting an error using this formula and can't figure out why...
Maybe because I don't have the column matching the date?

[image]

It should return 3.
Criteria range is G2:G4

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your formula, INDEX returns a 4-Row by 3-Column array, hence the error.  Try the following instead...

```
=INDEX(C2:E5,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A5=G2)*(B2:B5=G3),0),0),MATCH(G4,C1:E1,0))
```